# During SCCM task sequence, is it possible to remove target machine from all collections?

Tags: sccm

I am attempting to create an 'end of life' task sequence for leased machines, and I would like to add an element to the sequence that removes the system from all collections (effectively removing it from SCCM).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I have confirmed the following works in sccm 2012:

```
Remove-CMDevice -DeviceName "$ComputerName" -Force
```

There is also an option for deviceID as well, I should mention that is a powershell cmdlet.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj821759.aspx